# How exactly do I import an xml file into Optaplanner to be used in the vehicle routing solution?

Tags: xml, optaplanner

I really would like to use `Optaplanner` for my website to solve the vehicle distribution problem, but I have no idea how to import my database info into the software.

I have a database that I'd like to set up to `Optaplanner`, but if that is not possible, then I'd like to know how to export my database info into an `XML` file that can be read by `Optaplanner`.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OptaPlanner's input and output is not XML, but java objects (POJO's). In the examples, these are persisted to/from XML on disk with the `XStreamSolutionDao` class, but also persisted to/from various txt formats with the `*Importer`/`Exporter` classes.

This means you can copy-paste the examplse and replace the `XStreamSolutionDao` with your own java implementation that goes to your database.

Also look at the class [`VehicleRoutingImporter`](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/persistence/VehicleRoutingImporter.java) for inspiration.